# Spring Batch: How to write to csv file from a Collection

Tags: spring-batch

I need to write to a CSV file from a Collection.

I created a class:

```
public class ItemWriterForCSVFile extends FlatFileItemWriter<Map<String, String>>{private LineAggregator<Map<String, String>> createLineAggregator() {
    DelimitedLineAggregator<Map<String, String>> lineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
    lineAggregator.setDelimiter(",");
    BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Map<String, String>> fieldExtractor = createFieldExtractor();
    lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);

    return lineAggregator;
}

private BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Map<String, String>> createFieldExtractor() {
    BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Map<String, String>> extractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
    extractor.setNames(fields);
    return extractor;
}}
```

Currently, I am have a code above, which extract fields from an object.
I need to change it to use a Map, as a dynamic structure.

I saw that PassThroughFieldExtractor can write a collection, but haven't find a suitable examples in java.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is an item in your case? `I saw that PassThroughFieldExtractor can write a collection`: a field extractor does not write anything, it extracts field values from an object. Where did you see that? If you can explain what you want to achieve without referring to Spring Batch, I can help you do it with Spring Batch.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, 
Thank you for your quick response. 
What I need to is:
Writer get a Map<String, String>, when key is column_name and value is column value.
I have a list of headers and columns , which should appear in the CSV file.
What I need is to write the map values to a csv file, in the same order as they are in headers.
What is the spring batch way to do it?